# PHPUnit How to test binary output?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a PHP class that outputs the appropriate `image/jpeg` content header, and JPG binary data.  I'd like to test the class using PHPUnit, to ensure it's outputting the correct image.

My testing method is:

```
public function testNotFound(){
    ob_start(NULL,0);
    Model\Photo::deliver('blabbityblabbyblab');
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    $this->assertEquals(50,strlen($content));
}
```

`Model\Photo` will output a particular, known image.  However, the assertion is never run, and I get an error generated by PHPUnit:

`Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers`

How do I only close the buffer I started in my test method?

Comment: maybe there is some error or warning in the Model\Photo::deliver sentence that makes PHPUnit interrupt the process before you close the buffer. What happens if you comment that sentence?+

Comment: Commenting out that test causes the assertion to properly fail as expected.  The only output `deliver` does though is output a `Content-type` header and jpg data.  Code pasted here: http://pastebin.com/eLAY7v6X

Comment: Headers are not capured by output buffering. Try sending the headers only if they're not already sent, checking it with headers_sent() php function.

Comment: @gontrollez: Adding that simply causes the binary data output by deliver() to get echoed to the screen.  I'm not sure why it's not getting caught by the output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This tripped me up recently as well. You appear to be using a later version of PHPUnit (e.g. 4.5). They [changed the way that output buffering is handled](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.output) by way of:

- `expectOutputString(string $expectedString)`
- `expectOutputRegex(string $regularExpression)`

I believe in your example you could use the RegEx method to make sure the expected EXIF data string appeared in the image or some other test.